# Unable to move the Stable Diffusion pipeline to my M1 MacBook

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

I am following the steps stated here: [How to use Stable Diffusion in Apple Silicon (M1/M2)](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/optimization/mps#how-to-use-stable-diffusion-in-apple-silicon-m1m2).

At my local MacBook M1 machine, I saved the below script in stable-diffusion.py file:

```
# make sure you're logged in with `huggingface-cli login`
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline

pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5")
pipe = pipe.to("mps")

# Recommended if your computer has < 64 GB of RAM
pipe.enable_attention_slicing()

prompt = "a photo of an astronaut riding a horse on mars"

# First-time "warmup" pass (see explanation above)
_ = pipe(prompt, num_inference_steps=1)

# Results match those from the CPU device after the warmup pass.
image = pipe(prompt).images[0]
```

Now when I am trying to execute: `python stable-diffusion.py` from Terminal, I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/Desktop/area_51/stable-diffusion.py", line 2, in <module>
    from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'diffusers'
```

In order to fix it even I tried: `pip install diffusers`, however I still got same error.

Am I missing anything over here?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing from source:

`pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers.git`

Worked for me.